# Is it possible to load compiled code to hint?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a library and I want my executable to be pretty much what I get when I `cabal repl` it, i.e. I want the user to be able to use Haskell expressions, and import the modules and use the data types that are defined in my library.

Is it possible? I get the idea that `hint` can only work with source files (which are not available to the user), but I'm not certain. When I tried to load modules from my library or from cabal packages that are globally installed, I got a vague error message saying that the module is a package module. In fact, almost whatever I write will do that too:

```
ghci> runInterpreter $ loadModules ["Not.A.Package.Module"]
Left (WontCompile [GhcError {errMsg = "<no location info>: error:\n    module \8216Not.A.Package.Module\8217 is a package module"}])
```

Is there any way to do this? (P.S. I'm using GHC 8.0.1 and `plugins` isn't supporting it, and I also got the idea it's a very dead project. If there's another way but `hint` & `plugins` I'm open to it).

Comment: Can ghci itself import these modules?

Answer (score 0):

You could make yourself a **stack** project and put your code on which you depend on Hackage.

Then in your project add that package into your `build-depends` section of the `*.cabal` file.
Then just import the stuff you need using `setImportsQ` from `hint`.

An example would be depending on `Chart` and `Chart-diagrams`:

```
build-depends:       base
                     ...
                     , Chart
                     , Chart-diagrams
```

And then in your evaluation function:

```
setImportsQ[ ("Prelude",Nothing)
           , ("Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Easy", Nothing)
           , ("Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Backend.Diagrams", Nothing)
           ]
```